# Bluetooth audio stuttering Windows 10 on Boot Camp on a MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, boot-camp

Setup I have:

1. MacBook Pro A1707 with Broadcom bluetooth and WiFi
2. Windows 10 18xx/19xx installed with Boot Camp and drivers
3. Marshal Minor II and Audiotechnica ATH-DSR7BT

Here the issues I am facing:

1. When "Add bluetooth device" window is open connected audio output stutters and is impossible to use.
2. When window from issue one is closed audio still breaks but with less frequency. 10-30 second intervals.

Comment: In my case I found that by bluetooth mouse somehow interferes with the bluetooth headset. As soon as I turn off the mouse, the audio stops stuttering.

Answer (score 3):

My fix was to turn off my computer (not restart it), wait for a few seconds for the cache to clean, and cold boot into Windows (DO NOT LET YOUR macOS SIDE LOAD) ... it worked.

Comment: This actually worked for me, with a 2017 MacBook Pro fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Both issues are related to a scan process of available devices.

I've fixed issue two by disabling "Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator" under:

> Device manager -> Bluetooth -> Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator

Comment: Doing this made no improvement for me. The bluetooth sound is still choppy on my 2017 MacBook Pro fully loaded.

Comment: This had no effect for me with a MacBook Pro 2017 fully loaded.

Comment: go to your `Device Manager -> Network adapters -> Broadcom 802.11ac ... ` and on the Advanced tab set `Bluetooth collaboration` to Auto.

Answer (score 0):

Played with every setting in Windows under Bluetooth without success.

I purchase an inexpensive Bluetooth dongle. It should be plug-and-play. Unpair the audio device.  Make sure you disable the in-built Bluetooth in Device Manager, go to Bluetooth, disable Bluetooth radio. Then plug in the new dongle. Reboot.

Re-pair your device and viola!

Comment: Why are you [posting multiple answers](https://superuser.com/a/1630823/167207)? Just post one answer and update it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the Apple Bluetooth keyboard and mouse (i am using radio mouse now) clearly solves the issue perfectly for me, BUT, I am typing this with he keyboard and listening to music, and disabling ARP Offload appears to have solved it, or at least significantly improved the cutouts to less than 1/min.

Answer (score -1):

Bootcamp bluetooth stutter fix

Settings> Device Manager > Network Adaptors > Broadcom 802.11ac > Advanced > ARP Offload > Disable

I'm running Bootcamp Windows 10 with a native bluetooth adaptor on my MacBook pro 15 '18 (i.e. built-in Bluetooth) with Sony WH-H910N bluetooth headphones

Comment: Why are you [posting multiple answers](https://superuser.com/a/1635175/167207)? Just post one answer and update it as needed.